# Symbol not visible in Layers panel

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, symbology, geometry-generator, panel

I have a layer with symbology that includes Geometry Generators. It would appear that because of these the symbol is not visible in the layers panel.

Is there a way to show the up most symbol (green square) in the panel?

[image]

**Following the answer by @NettaB**

As suggested I tried locking the marker but the after clicking okay the symbol flashes up for a short period then disappears.

[image]

**Geometry generator expressions**

For the line:

```
make_line(make_point($x, $y), make_point("xcoord", "ycoord"))
```

For the marker:

```
 make_point("xcoord","ycoord")
```

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using? Seems to work fine for me on 3.6.2. Maybe dependant on the layer type? Is it a shapefile or geopackage?

Comment: I am using QGIS 3.4.8 and it is a shapefile.

Comment: @AWGIS can you check if the 'simple marker' layer is locked?

Comment: Can you post an image of what is actually showing where you'd like the green square to show? I assume you're trying to map a point feature here. If what is currently being mapped is one of the geometry generator symbols (e.g. the circle labelled 'Marker'), you should be able to edit the symbology to match the green square that you want as the marker.

Comment: Thanks. No symbol is currently showing in the layers panel - it is currently blank unfortunately.

Comment: @NettaB please can you confirm how I do that?

Comment: @AWGIS - Sounds similar to [this issue](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/21301). What happens if you change from _Single symbol_ to _Rule-based_?

Comment: @Joseph yes it does - thank you for pointing that out to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this will help, can you please see if the upmost symbol (green square) is locked in the symbology definition?
[image]

Edit: I've tried it and the symbol is showing by the layer's name
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I tried locking as you suggested and the symbol flashes up for a couple of seconds then proceeds by disappearing again. I am starting to think it could be a bug

Comment: I have added a GIF showing me trying your suggestion.

Comment: @AWGIS what version of qgis are you using?

Comment: I am using version 3.4.8

Comment: @AWGIS I'll try v3.6 later. Can you also check if after close & reopen of QGIS you can see the symbol?

Comment: Thank you - I can confirm that upon saving and re-opening the symbol appears briefly but then disappears

Comment: @AWGIS - a. it is working properly for me in 3.4.4 b. If youll send me the expression you are using in the geometry generator I can also check it. best of luck :)

Comment: I will add the expression to my question as an edit. Thanks